# receive unknown number of file descriptors over a UNIX domain socket

Tags: c, linux, unix-socket

When receiving file descriptos over a UNIX domain socket, one needs to initialize `struct msghdr.msghdr` (and `struct msghdr.msg_controllen`) to point to a buffer sufficient large to accept N number of file descriptors.

In my case, however, I don't know a priori the number of file descriptors that are being sent. It appears that if the buffer pointed to by `struct msghdr.msghdr` is not large enough then the file descriptors that don't fit in it are silently dropped.

How can I make sure this doesn't happen? The only possible solution I can think of is for both ends to agree to a maximum value of N and make sure the recepient uses a sufficiently large buffer in `struct msghdr.msghdr`.

Comment: Send the number of descriptors like normal over the socket and then send them?